# TooManyLockFailure : Too many lock failure 200 Trying again later

Tags: apex, apex-sharing

I have a requirement to provide a particular group of records to one user.But record sharing criteria depends on formula field.

So, I'm not able to share through sharing rules. So, I have created an apex to share opportunity access to the users.

But I'm facing this error.

> TooManyLockFailure: Too many lock failure 200 Trying again later.

Apex Class

```
public class OpportunitySharing 
{
    Public static Boolean Sharingcheck=true;
    public static ID userid=[Select id from user where name='Chloe Rodriguez'].ID;
    public static void BangaloreTeamShareUpdateordelete(List<Opportunity> newopps,Map<Id,Opportunity> oldmapopps)
    {
        List<Id> Sharedeletionlist = new List<Id>();
        List<OpportunityShare> Shareinsertlist = new List<OpportunityShare>();
        for(Opportunity oppid:newopps)
        {
            if(oldmapopps.get(oppid.id).team__c == 'Bangalore Team' && 
               (oppid.Team__c <> 'Bangalore Team' || String.isBlank(oppid.Team__c)) )
            {
                Sharedeletionlist.add(oppid.id);
            }
            else if((oldmapopps.get(oppid.Id).team__c <> 'Bangalore Team' || String.isBlank(oldmapopps.get(oppid.id).team__c)) && 
                    oppid.Team__c == 'Bangalore Team')
            {
                Opportunityshare oppshareid= new  Opportunityshare();
                oppshareid.Opportunityid=oppid.Id;
                oppshareid.UserOrGroupId=userid;
                oppshareid.OpportunityAccessLevel='edit';
                Shareinsertlist.add(oppshareid);
            }
        }
            if(Sharedeletionlist <> null && !Sharedeletionlist.isEmpty())
            {
                delete[Select id from Opportunityshare where opportunityid IN :Sharedeletionlist AND RowCause='Manual' FOR UPDATE];
            }
            If(Shareinsertlist <> null && !Shareinsertlist.isEmpty())
            {
                insert Shareinsertlist;
            }
    }
}
```

Please guide where I missed it.

Comment: Why are you using an explicit `FOR UPDATE` on a `delete` DML here?

Comment: I thought records are locking because of that query.Already i have removed from my code